# Linq to SQL replace .Any() with .Contains()

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Got a dictionary with the persons Id as a key. And each value is a List with a class that contains a datetime.

I want to get all contracts from the database where each date in the list is in between the contracts from and until -date. There could be multiple for each person.

I can't use .Any() function. If I do I'll get this error: " Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

This is an example with the .Any method that doesn't work with linq to sql. And I need an other way to manage this.

```
public class SimpleObject
    {
        public bool Test { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }

    private void Test(Dictionary<int, List<SimpleObject>> dataBaseObjDictionary)
    {
        using (var db = TpContext.Create())
        {
            var selectedObj = db.Contracts.Where(x => dataBaseObjDictionary.ContainsKey(x.PersonRef) && dataBaseObjDictionary.Values.Any(y => y.Any(a => x.FromDate <= a.DateTime) && y.Any(a=>a.DateTime >= x.UntilDate)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that linq to sql doesn't know how to translate method ContainsKey to SQL, try to rewrite dataBaseObjDictionary.ContainsKey(x.PersonRef) as dataBaseObjDictionary.Keys.Contains(x.PersonRef).

Comment: I'd even take it a step further, and try to make the LINQ query as simple as possible so there's less that can go wrong: `int[] keys = dataBaseObjDictionary.Keys.ToArray(); ... .Where(x => keys.Contains(x.PersonRef)...`. I don't know if it would make a difference, but I know with Entity Framework, I've seen it complain at runtime about similar things, so you have to keep the LINQ simple.

Comment: Made an edit to my question. The thing is that I can't use the .Any() method. It trows me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it. It looks like you were relying on y to be the same with the two y.anys. In addition, you were checking if a was greater than until date and greater than from date so I fixed those.

```
var selectedObj = db.Contracts.Where(x => dataBaseObjDictionary.ContainsKey(x.PersonRef) 
                && dataBaseObjDictionary.Values.Any(
                y => y.Any(a => x.FromDate <= a.DateTime 
                        && a.DateTime <=  x.UntilDate)
                       )
                );
```

Comment: But I can't use .Any function when operating against the DB. I get this error: "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementation of query operators except the Contains() operator."

Comment: Can you use .Count > 0? Also that error doesn't explicitly name .Any as the problem. It may very well be the ContainsKey.

Comment: Tried that as well, but unfortunatley not! Same error. I need to use contains. I'll make another solution with a bigger query instead of filter on dates.